# Sarcastic or rhetorical use of 'and who can blame him?'

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

Is the phrase *"...and who can blame him?"* ever used in a sarcastic or rhetorical manner when referring to someone who is in reality very blameworthy?

What is the meaning that is conveyed when this term is used generally?

Comment: *Who can blame him?* usually means that the person under consideration has made a reasonable choice under the circumstances.

Comment: It can also be said about an action without any better alternatives, even if the action itself seems ill-advised.

Answer (score 1):

***I don't** (or **can't**) **blame you** (or **her** etc.)* — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/i-don%27t-or-can%27t-blame-you-or-her-etc.)

> Used to indicate that one agrees that the action or attitude taken was reasonable
>
> *"he was becoming impatient and I couldn’t blame him"*
> *"If you are confused by all this, I don't blame you."*
> *"I guess I can't blame him for being impatient, if indeed he is and not simply excited."*

When it is changed to *"Who can blame him?"*, it's almost always a rhetorical question that means the same thing as *"I don't blame him"*.

See usage examples in [Google Books](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Who%20can%20blame%20him%22)